# UIImage set image vs AVPlayer seek method choice

Tags: ios, video, uiimageview, avplayer

This is an video editor app's screenshot, this feature is about finding a frame in the video as the video's cover, and send all the video and frame image to the server.

In the red part, the editor use *AVAssetImageGenerator* generates a series of image as preview.You can slide the orange part view in the red part from left to right.When you slide the orange view, this view will change the image inside itself, just like *AVPlayer* *seek:* method effect, I want to know whether set this orange part as *AVPlayer* to use *seek:* method, or set this part as *UIImageView* to change its *image* property? Will these ways affect performance?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I use the AVPlayer in the orange part, by *seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:* method, it can preview accurate frame at the right time, and the performance is pretty well.